# When I started jboss in eclipse actually what is mean by these line of code in console?

Tags: java, jboss

Actually I'm new to jboss server. Today I just configure the jboss 7.1 in eclipse indigo. When I started the server it is started successfully. But what is these line of code tells about?

12:50:46,192 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS017100: Listening on localhost/127.0.0.1:4447

12:50:46,194 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on /127.0.0.1:9999

12:50:47,772 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990

12:50:47,774 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" started in 34526ms - Started 133 of 208 services (74 services are passive or on-demand)

I want each line what is actually telling? localhost listening to different port in first and second and third. But Jboss loaded in http://localhost:8080/

Answer (score 0):

`MSC` states for *Modular Service Container*. Each thread should take care of dependency injection of values inside the container.
See [documentation](http://jboss-msc.github.io/jboss-msc/apidocs/).

`Controller Boot Thread` is the thread which manage the booting of the application server.